# Error en arreglo inverso

Tags: c#, array, ciclos

Hice un arreglo de 10 elementos, y luego otro arreglo con la misma cantidad del 1ro pero el contenido es inverso, ejemplo:

*Lista 1:*
**1.** 20
**2.** 34
**3.** 12
*Lista 2:*
**10.** 20
**9.** 34
**8.** 12

Y así...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] lista1 = new int [10];
        int [] lista2 = new int [10];
        generarListas(lista1, lista2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void generarListas(int[] lista1, int[] lista2)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= lista1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            lista1[i-1] = random.Next(1, 50);
            Console.WriteLine("N " +i+ " - " +(lista1[i-1]));

        }
        for (int n = 1; n <= lista2.GetLength(0); n++)
        {
            lista2[lista2.GetLength(0) - n] = lista1[n - 1];
            Console.WriteLine("N " +n+ " - " +(lista2[n - 1]));
        }
    }
```

Pero me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El array se está construyendo bien. El problema es que estás intentando mostrar elementos del array antes de asignarlos... Si agregás un 3er bucle para mostrar el contenido de `lista2` lo vas a ver bien... Aunque realmente te convendría usar valores más prácticos en los contadores de cada bucle... Y podés usar `lista2.Length` para sacar el largp

Comment: Y si no fuese una ejercicio de tarea: `int [] lista2 = (int[])lista1.Clone(); Array.Reverse(lista2);`